# Eloquent\model injection into method returns null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I have problem with fetching model using injected Eloquent into controllers method - it dosne't find model using id in URL.
I remeber that I changed in other Controller

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

dd($infrastructure) returns just meta data about Model:

```
Infrastructure {#257 ▼
#table: "infrastructures"
#fillable: array:10 [▶]
#connection: null
#primaryKey: "id"
....
}
```

My controllers method:

```
public function show(Infrastructure $infrastructure)
{

    $card = [];
    $card['name'] = $infrastructure->name;
    $card['id'] = $infrastructure->id;
    $card['type'] = "infrastructure";
    $card['items']['manufacturer'] = $infrastructure->manufacturer;
    $card['items']['type'] = $infrastructure->infrastructuretype()->first()-   >name;
    $card['items']['kind'] = $infrastructure->kind()->first()->name;
    $card['items']['serial'] = $infrastructure->serial;
    $card['items']['more info'] = Crypt::decrypt($infrastructure->long_desc);

    $title = 'Infrastructure details ';

    $warranty_left = $infrastructure->warranty_date > $infrastructure->purchase_date ? (new Carbon($infrastructure->warranty_date))->diffInDays(new Carbon($infrastructure->purchase_date)) : 0;

    return view('infrastructure.show', compact('infrastructure', 'card', 'title'));
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::model('infrastructure', 'App\Infrastructure');


Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::resource('infrastructure', 'InfrastructureController');
get('infrastructure/{infrastructure}/logs', [
    'uses' => 'InfrastructureController@showInfrastructureLogs'
]);
resource('infrastructuretype', 'InfrastructureTypeController');


Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this stopped working but ruuning

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file change `Route::model('infrastructure', 'App\Infrastructure');` to `Route::bind('infrastructure', 'App\Infrastructure');`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Route::resource defines the wildcard with plural names, which would make the wildcard 'infrastructures'.

You are binding the 'infrastructure' wildcard to the model, which would only work for your  showInfrastructureLog method.

You can use this command in the console to show each resource full path:

```
php artisan route:list
```

You can easily fix this by changing

```
Route::model('infrastructure', 'App\Infrastructure');
```

To

```
Route::model('infrastructure', 'App\Infrastructure');
```

(I've never personally used Route::model for model binding, always did it from the RouteServiceProvider, but i assume it works)

Also change the wildcard in the  'infrastructure/{infrastructure}/logs' to 'infrastructures'

Comment: I didn't understant what change  to what. You wrote to same lines.

Comment: Route::model('infrastructures', 'App\Infrastructure'); should have been the second one, my bad